# How to change timepicker interval value change dynamic?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

In timepicker set interval time first time after that no change interval time. Interval time come from dynamically.

I got interval value dynamic but not display in my timepicker.

```
<script>
    $('#book_time').attr('disabled', true);
    $('#book_date').datetimepicker({
        timepicker: false,
        format: 'm-d-Y',
        minDate: 0,
        onSelectDate: function (ct, $i) {
            var branch = $('#branch_id').val();
            // console.log($i.val());
            if (branch == '')
            {
                alert("Please select the branch");
                $('#book_date').val('');
            } else
            {
                $('#book_time').change();

                let data = {
                    branch_id: branch,
                    booking_date: $i.val(),
                    delivery_type: "A"
                }

                $('#book_time').attr('placeholder', 'Please wait...');
                axios.post('<?= SIET_URL ?>book_table_time_management.php', data)
                    .then(response => {
                        $('#book_time').attr('disabled', false);
                        $('#book_time').attr('placeholder', '');
                        var interval = response.data.stepsDay;
                        console.log(interval);
                        $('#book_time').timepicker({
                            // console.log(response.data.stepsDay);
                            timeFormat: 'hh:mm p',
                            interval: interval,
                            minTime: response.data.startTime,
                            maxTime: response.data.endTime,
                            startTime: response.data.startTime,
                            // changeinterval:true,
                            dynamic: true,
                            dropdown: true,
                            scrollbar: true
                        });

                        console.log(response.data.stepsDay);
                        // };

                    })

                    .catch(error => {

                    });
            }
        }
    });
</script>
```

I want to change timepicker interval value change.

Comment: Does `$('#book_time').val();` work? For example `$('#book_time').val("09:30 AM");`.

Comment: i know this thing but #('book_time').timepicker() get minTime,maxTime,Interval come to dynamic. and interval time and all change according to that dynamic value.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean.